# Doubts about Astah Community with Oracle Java 9 or JDK 1.8

Tags: java, jdk

I have a little problem here, I got Astah Community in my PC but it didnt work until I change my Java.
I need to make this commands always when I need to use Astah:

```
max@Max-Notebook:~$ sudo update-alternatives --config java

There are 2 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

  Selection    Path                                 Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-oracle/bin/java   1091      auto mode
  1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-oracle/bin/java   1091      manual mode
* 2            /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0/bin/java        1         manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

By default I use the option 1 as you can see, but i need to change to option 2 before open Astah.
I want to know why I need that and how i can solve this problem. I can't uninstall Oracle Java 9 because I need that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved that by removing all JDK and Java's from my PC and installing "oracle-java8-installer" package from ppa:webupd8team/java